# How to Run a Command in a Container Using Local Input Files without Copying

Tags: docker, containers, local

I am new to docker and containers. I have a container consisting of an MRI analysis software. Within this container are many other software the main software draws its commands from. I would like to run a single command from one of the softwares in this container using research data that is located on an external hard drive which is plugged into my local machine that is running docker.

I know there is a `cp` command for copying files (such as scripts) into containers and most other questions along these lines seem to recommend copying the files from your local machine into the container and then running the script (or whatever) from the container. In my case I need the container to access data from separate folders in a directory structure and copying over the entire directory is not feasible since it is quite large.

I honestly just want to know how I can run a single command inside the docker using inputs present on my local machine. I have run `docker ps` to get the `CONTAINER_ID` which is d8dbcf705ee7. Having looked into executing commands inside containers I tried the following command:

`docker exec d8dbcf705ee7 /bin/bash -c "mcflirt -in /Volumes/DISS/FMRIPREP/sub-S06V1A/func/sub-S06V1A_task-compound_run-01_bold.nii -out sub-S06V1A_task-compound_run-01_bold_mcf_COMMAND_TEST.nii.gz -reffile /Volumes/DISS/FMRIPREP_TMP/sub-S06V1A_dof6_ver1.2.5/fmriprep_wf/single_subject_S06V1A_wf/func_preproc_task_compound_run_01_wf/bold_reference_wf/gen_ref/ref_image.nii.gz -mats -plots"`

`mcflirt` is the command I want to run inside the container. I believe the `exec` command would do what I hope since if I run `docker exec d8dbcf705ee7 /bin/bash -c "mcflirt"` I will get help output for the `mcflirt` command which is the expected outcome in that case. The files inside of the `/Volume/...` paths are the files on my local machine I would like to access. I understand that the location of the files is the problem since I cannot tab complete the paths within this command; when I run this I get the following output:

`Image Exception : #22 :: ERROR: Could not open image /Volumes/DISS/FMRIPREP/sub-S06V1A/func/sub-S06V1A_task-compound_run-01_bold
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'RBD_COMMON::BaseException'`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One of the major goals of Docker is isolating containers' filesystems from the host.  This setup really sounds like you don't want Docker at all.

Comment: It's a weird situation. The software analysis package is distributed via docker which you can normally use on your local files via a program call. However I am getting disparate results when using the package compared to running the individual commands on my local machine. One of the developers suggested to 'go inside the container and run the command with your inputs.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I got you right, you need to execute some `shell` script and provide the context (like local files).

The way is straightforward.

Lets say your script and all needed files are located in `/hello` folder of your **host** PC (no matter really if they are stored together or not, just showing the technique).

```
/hello
  - runme.sh
  - datafile1
  - datafile1
```

You mount this folder into your container to make the files accessible inside. If you **dont** need container to modify them, better mount in `readonly` mode.

You launch docker like this:

```
docker run -it -v /hello:/hello2:ro ubuntu /hello2/runme.sh
```

And that's it! Your script `runme.sh` gets executed inside container and it has access to nearby files. Thanks to `-v /hello:/hello2:ro` directive. It maps host's folder `/hello` into container's folder `/hello2` in readonly `ro` mode.

Note you can have same names, I've just differed them to show the difference.

Comment: I use this trick a lot `docker run -v "$PWD:$PWD" -w "$PWD" ...`

Comment: In my situation the command I'm trying to run is not on the host machine but is in the container; I believe it is located in `/usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin` in the container. In this scenario it seems like the command would start the same -
`docker run -it -v /hello:hello2:ro d8dbcf705ee7 ?/?` but I'm not sure what to do with the last part.

Also, does it matter if what I'd like to run is not a script but is instead just a command on the command line like above (with inputs and outputs specified on the command line)?

I really appreciate your response. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @chainhomelow if your command is inside container, just launch it instead of shell script in my example. Something like `docker run -it -v /hello:/hello2:ro ubuntu /usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin/blahblah`. You still will have access to `/hello2` folder. The type of executable doesnt matter - if it is a script or compiled. You can do whatever you like in Linux, but if you need several command to be executed, you need to run them with `sh -c`, like: `docker run -it -v /hello:/hello2:ro ubuntu sh -c "echo Hello && echo World"`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the comment about the addition of the `sh -c` for multiple commands as that seemed to be one of the problems I ended up facing in the grand scheme of things. Thank you, I very much appreciate your time in explaining this.